# Elasticsearch 1.7.6 cluster discovery in Kubernetes

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I Have an ES Cluster running on Kubernetes (EKS). I'm trying to get discovery to work.

I Have verified I have network access between the pods on 9200,9300 (Got Calico Running on the Cluster. Verified the policy allows 9200,9300)

I would like to implement discovery and I wonder if I'm missing something.

1. Does Elasticearch 1.7 supports more methods for discovery apart from multicast/unicast?

> we prefer to avoid unicast since this is a Kubernetes cluster.

2. Is there a way to use multicast with Calico?

For reference here is the configuration:

Elasticsearch.yml

```
 cluster.name: <CLUSTER_NAME>
 node.name: "${MY_POD_NAME}"
 node.master: true
 node.data: true
 bootstrap.mlockall: false
 discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: true
 indices.memory.index_buffer_size: 30%
 indices.cache.filter.size: 20%
 indices.fielddata.cache.size: 20%
 index.translog.flush_threshold_ops: 8192
 threadpool.bulk.queue_size: 1546
 http.max_initial_line_length: 16K
 script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs: off
 script.engine.groovy.inline.search: off
 index.number_of_replicas: 1
 threadpool.search.queue_size: 10000
 index.number_of_shards: 3
 threadpool.bulk.queue_size: 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Elasticsearch v7+, `discovery.zen.*` is no longer in use. Instead, use the following settings:

**elasticsearch.yml:**

```yaml
cluster.initial_master_nodes: es-cluster-0,es-cluster-1,es-cluster-2 # node name with master roles
discovery.seed_hosts: es-cluster # k8s headless service that point to all pods/nodes
```

- [discovery.seed_hosts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.7/modules-discovery-hosts-providers.html#settings-based-hosts-provider)

Comment: I am asking specifically on Elasticsearch 1.7.*